# Silverlight equivalent to signed Java Applet?

Tags: c#, silverlight, security, sandbox, signed-applet

Is there a Silverlight equivalent to signed applets in Java?

I'm basically trying to host what would traditionally be a desktop application in a browser*, and I'd rather do it all in a single package (the Silverlight end) rather than delegate privileged actions to an outside (locally running) process.  This would require some way of breaking out of Silverlight's sandbox though; the only equivalent I'm aware of are Java's signed applets, and I can't find anything similar.

<sub>*There are good usability reasons for this, technically it does complicate things</sub>

Comment: +1 because now I know how to do footnotes. :)

Comment: What functionality do you need that silverlight is not offering. Local file access?

Comment: Device access.  Bluetooth stack at the moment.  Other features may come up that require more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need full access to local resources, Silverlight isn't going to get you there. You could use [XBAPs](http://www.xbap.org/) to run in-browser on the "big" CLR, but even there, the security model is painful (you have to run a local install to the GAC to get full trust). You might want to have a look at the forthcoming .NET 4.0 as well- they've redone some of the security layer to simplify things, though I don't know if/how it affects XBAPs. There's a great post about FullTrust XBAPs in .NET 3.5 [here](http://scorbs.com/2007/01/10/xbap-trust-levels/).

Answer (score 1):

You can still create ActiveX controls with C#/.Net <sup>1</sup>.

<sup>1</sup> <sub>I'm not saying this is a great idea, I'm just saying it *can* be done. Also experimenting with footnotes for the first time.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

If you are not constrained to .net, you can also use adobe air.

---

If constrained to .net and based on access to resources beyond silverlight/xabp reach, you could:

- host a .net control in the browser ... explicitely allowing access to the resource you need on the client side ... I don't recall the exacts of this, but our team did once this for an intranet resource that needed to access of some local resources.
- do a non browser desktop client app instead

Comment: Very nearly the entire project is .NET; for simplicities sake (simplicity of build anyway) I'd rather stick with .NET technologies.